# Reading a CSV file & sending the contents of the CSV file as a e-mail message content using Python

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a CSV file and Using python , I need to read the file and send the contents of CSV in a email message not as a attachment. Using the below script , It works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

me = 'me@gmail.com'
password = 'passWord'
server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
you = 'you@gmail.com'

text = """
Hello Team,

Import Status :

{table}

Regards,

Arun"""

html = """
<html><body><p>Hello Team,</p>
<p>Import Status :</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Arun</p>
</body></html>
"""

with open('/home/files/daily_import/import.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)
    print data
text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
print text
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
print html

message = MIMEMultipart( "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])
message['Subject'] = "Test Mail - Import Status"
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(me, password)
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()
```

But using the above script sends the mail in a un-impressive way. The first line of the CSV values is highlighted.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to send the email without the first line of CSV content highlighted and also in a interactive tabular column in a email like below ?

CSV File :

[image]

Comment: When I am trying to implement similar kind of scenario it shows the error : " ImportError: No module named tabulate ". However when I am trying to install tabulate, it doesn't allow me to do so. is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row is highlighted because your invocation includes `headers="firstrow"`. It should work better if you just remove that named argument completely.

To get borders around the table cells, you'll probably want to define your own TableFormat, instead of relying on the `html` format predefined by the module. For instance, this is what `html` gives you:

```
myformat = TableFormat(lineabove=Line("<table>", "", "", ""),
                       linebelowheader=None,
                       linebetweenrows=None,
                       linebelow=Line("</table>", "", "", ""),
                       headerrow=partial(tabulate._html_row_with_attrs, "th"),
                       datarow=partial(tabulate._html_row_with_attrs, "td"),
                       padding=0, with_header_hide=None)
```

Experiment with changes to that, and pass `myformat` instead of `"html"` as the value of the `tablefmt` parameter.